# What is the meaning of the chaining of => (rightward double arrow) operator in Scala's function literal?

Tags: scala

What is the meaning of chaining of `=>` operator like in this code:

```
val a = Array("I", "love", "Scala Johnson")
a.foreach {
    x => y: String => println(x)
}
```

It printed out nothing.

So what happened? Does the `x` lost in compilation?

If I removed `String` type declaration from `y` parameter:

```
x => y => println(x)
```

I got `"missing parameter type"` compile error.

Then I did an experiment:

```
val hotFunc: Int => Int => Unit = x => y => println(x * y)
hotFunc(2)(11)
```

It printed out `22`.

So, does the chaining of `=>` mean currying?

**UPDATE:**

The 3rd case:

```
def readFile[T](f: File)(handler: FileInputStream => T): T = {
    val resource = new java.io.FileInputStream(f)
    try {
        handler(resource)
    } finally {
        resource.close()
    }
}

val bs = new Array[Byte](4)

readFile(new File("Slurp.scala")) {
    input => b: Byte => println("Read: " + (input.read(bs) + b))
}
```

It's same with 1st example, printed out nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=>` is right associative, so in your first example you are calling a function with the values of `a`, which return a function `String=>Unit` (but that never get caught, get converted implicitly to `Unit` because of `foreach`). Probably it would be more clear with parentheses:

```
x => ((y: String) => println(x))
```

which turned to

```
x => ((y: String) => println(x); ())
```

in `foreach`, because it expects `T => Unit`.

Chaining of `=>` (without parentheses) is kind of currying, yes.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still a bit confused. Please look at 3rd example, what happened there?

Comment: @suud You have not called the returned `Byte => Unit` function, so that is the expected behaviour for the 3rd example too (I think it closes the stream before you could read though, so invoking the function most probably causes an `IOException`).

Comment: Ok, I understand now. The `readFile` returns a function value (`b: Byte => println("Read: " + (input.read(bs) + b)` with type of `Byte => Unit`), it doesn't execute the code inside the function value, that's why nothing get printed out.